# javascript in nested table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a program, and would like to do thing (CSS/JavaScript) in nested table, but I met some problem.

I’d like to show something in the odd `tr` element in `tbody`, which is:

```
<tr>
    <th>0</th>
    <th>Match Key</th>
    <th>Marketing</th>
</tr>
```

and

```
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>Match Key</th>
    <th>Marketing</th>
</tr>
```

in my program, but when I use JavaScript or CSS, it will apply to the child table.

How can I escape child table in JavaScript and CSS?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7Pv/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want styling to apply to, say, a table-cell in `#report`, but not apply to a cell in a nested table, you can use this:

```
#report > tbody > tr > td{ /*some styles*/ }
```

the `>` character in the CSS selector is called the child selector

So, for example `#reports > tbody > tr` selects only a table-row that is a direct child of a `tbody` that is a direct child to `#reports`

Answer (score 1):

you would have to target the immediate child of the `tbody` with >

```
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th{
        background-color: #f00;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7Pv/8/)

for jquery use the same selector as above to target the `th`

if you are using javascript add class 'top' to the top level `<tr>` and this should work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7Pv/11/)

```
var tb = document.getElementById('report').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var trs = tb.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var newtr = new Array();
var count = 0;
for(i = 0;i<trs.length;i++){
    if(trs[i].className == 'top'){
        newtr[count] = trs[i];
        count++;
    }

}
for(i=0;i<newtr.length;i++){
    console.log(i)
    if(i%2 == 0){
        for(k=0;k<newtr[i].getElementsByTagName('th').length;k++){
            newtr[i].getElementsByTagName('th')[k].style.background = 'red';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/Zfg93/)

```
#report > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n+1) > th{
        background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: How can I do it in Javascript with any action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JavaScript Solution.

**JavaScript**

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    totalTr = tr.length;

for(var i = 0; i <= totalTr; i++){
    if( i%2 === 0 ){
        tr[i].className = 'odd';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="500">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.odd{background:#e5e5e5;}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wCMLK/)**